# Can only move one top answer in CV per page load, and can't tell it worked until reload

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, stack-overflow-jobs

There's a section in editing one's CV for including top answers (on SO and elsewhere). Each of the answers in there has three on-hover buttons: remove, up, and down. But if you click the up or down arrow on any of these, exactly one thing happens: the up and down arrows disappear and do not reappear for any answers on hover.

Notably, no answers visibly reorder themselves.

Reloading the page shows the answers in the expected new order, and allows moving one more answer in the same fashion. Adding a new answer does the same two things, but removing one changes nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now fixed. Answers move up and down when clicking arrows.

Thank you for the report!